# C: how to clear out buffer from a read() on a socket

Tags: c, string, sockets, buffer

I am trying to receive data from a server, and it works fine for the first time, but as read() keeps looping it will also store the old values it previously read. Here is what i have so far.

```
        char receive[50];

        if((he = gethostbyname(servername)) == NULL ) {

            perror(strcat("Cannot find server named:", servername));
            exit(0);
        }

        he = gethostbyname("localhost");
        localIP = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)*he->h_addr_list);
        client_sock_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(localIP);
        server_addr.sin_port = htons(serverport);
        len = sizeof(server_addr);
        if(connect(client_sock_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,len) == -1) {
            perror("Client failed to connect");
            exit(0);
        }

        strcpy(buf, "CLIENT/REQUEST\n");
        send(client_sock_desc, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
        //send actual function request

        //put a space before \n char to make it easier for the server
        for(i = 0; i < sizeof(wholeRequest); i++) {
            if(wholeRequest[i] == '\n') {
                wholeRequest[i] = ' ';
                wholeRequest[i+1] = '\n';
                break;
            }
        }

        while(read(client_sock_desc, receive, sizeof(receive)) > 0) {
            strcpy(receive, ""); //attempt to erase all old values
            printf(receive);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        close(client_sock_desc);
```

When the server sends data once and closes the socket, it works perfectly. But then I have the client open the socket again, send data to the server, and the server will once again send data to the client and close the socket. The client will again try to read the data the server sent, but this time it fills receive with both the new information and part of the old information

Comment: Does your server return null-terminated strings? I would suspect setting `receive[0]='\0'` would be a good way to clear the string. As it is, since you "clear" `receive` before printing it out, how do you ever get any output? Could it be because you need `printf("%s", receive)`? I am not sure how `printf` reacts when the format string is `""`...

Comment: i "clear" the receive after i print it out, so when i do the `read()` again, it will hopefully fill an empty `receive` with only the current values it received from the server

Comment: No - you "clear" the receive in the `strcpy` line, which, in your code above, happens BEFORE the `printf`. The `fflush` just means that everything that `printf` was going to output to `stdout` actually goes to the console before executing the next line. That is "flushing the buffer", and you are doing it on the OUTPUT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that in your code you delete the received data before printing it - then you pass a string to `printf` that is basically empty, and I'm not sure what `printf` does with that (since it is the formatting string that is empty).

Try this:

```
int nread;
while((nread = read(client_sock_desc, receive, sizeof(receive)-1)) > 0) {
        receive[nread]='\0';    // explicit null termination: updated based on comments
        printf("%s\n",receive); // print the current receive buffer with a newline
        fflush(stdout);         // make sure everything makes it to the output
        receive[0]='\0';        // clear the buffer : I am 99% sure this is not needed now
    }
```

Comment: weird thing is, this solution works better than the other one, but I am still getting half of the old data sent by the server into `receive`

Comment: it works now, i just looped through all 1024 index's of the receive string and changed them to `'\0'`. It works but i feel so wrong, i thought thats what `strcpy(receive, "")` was supposed to do! Hackiest fix ever lol

Comment: I was editing the question with the fix to that when your comment came in... count the number of characters read, then append the `'\0'` manually at the right place. Less hacky than zero filling the whole buffer...

Comment: Heres some sample output --- 
Enter command:
multiply 1 2 3
SERVER/RESULT
multiply 1 2 3 
6
Enter command:
multiply 1 2
SERVER/MISMATCH
multiply 2 3
**multiply 1 2 3 
6**. The part i bolded is clearly part of the old result. Only "SERVER/MISMATCH multiply 2 3" should be in the received in `receive`

Comment: Is that before you applied the latest fix, or after?

Comment: Btw, even when I append '\0' to the right place of receive, it still contains data from the old result. Here is some data i got after trying that: Enter command:
multiply 1 2 3
SERVER/RESULT
multiply 1 2 3 
6
Enter command:
multiply 2 1
SERVER/MISMATCH
multiply 2 3
**
6**. The bolded character should not have been in the result, and was from the old values.

Comment: The comment I just posted 5 minutes ago was before I applied any fix. The comment before this one was after I applied your recent suggestion

Comment: Your `printf` should not print past the null terminating character! Let's debug. Change your printf code to: `printf("number of characters: %d; string: %s\n", nread, receive);` . Did you notice I am reading`sizeof(receive)-1` characters, not `sizeof(receive)`?

Comment: One more thing: you say "looped through all 1024 indexes of the receive string", but you set aside a block of just 50 characters earlier with `char receive[50];` Are you writing all over some other variables?

Comment: sorry I actually meant to put receive[1024]. But i will try your fix in 5 minutes I am just attempting to fix something else real fast.